# On error Resume next in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

HI,

I want to catch SQL error in my Page.If I use "On error Resume next" ,If page having some other error it wont thrown .Can u plese give solution for handling error

Answer (score 3):

You can revert the standard exception raising by using

```
ON ERROR GOTO 0
```

http://www.powerasp.com/content/new/on-error-resume-next.asp

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't forget that if you put On Error Resume Next in a Sub or a Function it will only apply to that Sub/Function.